# Calculate NDVI with converted canon sx260 hs

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing

I have converted my canon sx260 hs so it can capture NIR part of specter. Can anyone tell me how can i calculate NDVI now? My guess is that on the blue channel is now NIR value and Green channel=(TRUE_GREEN + NIR) And Red channel =(TRUE_RED + NIR) So NDVI would be: NDVI= (NIR-TRUE_RED)/(NIR+TRUE_RED) 
 Am i on the right tracks?
 Any hints?

Comment: Can you describe which method you used to convert your camera? This is rather important when answering your question.

Comment: I used this NGB filter:
http://www.dronecenter.com.br/produto.php?cod_produto=8284990   
 It seems that formula is BNDVI=(NIR-BLUE) / (NIR+BLUE)

Comment: Yes. The filter you are using maps NIR to red, green to green and blue to blue. Thus, NDVI is not possible, but BNDVI is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Can you tell me what are range values for BNDVI(e.g. vegetation, soil...)
Is there some resource that you know for this index?

Comment: You can calculate how it should look in theory by taking values from the ASTER spectral library - http://speclib.jpl.nasa.gov/ - for example http://speclib.jpl.nasa.gov/speclibdata/jhu.becknic.soil.inceptisol.xerumbrept.coarse.87P325.spectrum.txt is a decent soil while http://speclib.jpl.nasa.gov/speclibdata/jhu.becknic.vegetation.trees.deciduous.solid.decidou.spectrum.txt represents a good decidous forest sample. As per the formula, your values with range from -1 to 1, with vegetation having a high value and soils near 0. The exact values will obviously depend on the camera settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you converted a Canon camera to pseudo-NIR by removing the NIR filter in front of the sensor, then you will end up with a blue/green/nir sensor (vegetation appears white). Indeed, all channels will be affected with extra intensity from the NIR depending on their sensitivity to this wavelength, with effect on RED >> BLUE > GREEN.  Red sensors are the most affected and the amount of NIR light is larger than visible light, so you don't have true red anymore. In this case you cannot compute NDVI because you are missing te Red and blue or green are not correlated with red to provide a substitute.

It is technically possible to create a Green/Red/NIR camera (vegetation appears red), but far more difficult (and I don't know how to do it). With such a camera, NDVI can be computed with your equation. Alternatively, you could try using two cameras (one with and one without IR cut filter) that you could register then compute your NDVI.